# Get count of all emails sent from an address in Gmail

Tags: gmail

Just for fun I wanted to know how many emails a friend has sent me over the years (in Gmail). I tried doing a search but the total only shows `x to y of z` where z is just an estimate. I then tried to go to the very last page (modified querystring) but realized Z is just number of conversations, which is not a true count of individual emails sent. I then tried creating a filter to see if that would give a more precise number, but it is the same.

Is there any built-in way in Gmail to find a real total of how many emails a user has sent?

My guess is the only way to get this is to import the email into a desktop app and use its counting mechanism.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try disabling [conversation view](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/09/threaded-email-or-not-now-its-your.html) and try running the search. That may help

Comment: You are right - this worked! I also noticed you can click on the x -y of z which shows options "newest/oldest" so very easy to get to the end. Grand total was 3279 :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to try going for the number of conversations - number of chats.

Comment: i am looking for exact number of emails. thanks though

Comment: That would have given the number of e-mails.